# VS Package Designer File Icons - What do they mean?

Tags: 2013, solution-package, visual-studio-2012

In a Mapped Folder what do these two different icons indicate about each file?

[image: Package Mapped Folder icons]

*This is just for illustration, the same file is not being deployed twice*

SharePoint 2013 Visual Studio 2012

Thanks

Comment: minified? ...maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first icon is Results to File. The result of some action, bundling sounds logical in this context.
The Second icon is Style sheet (css) that it is a stylesheet file.

[Visual studio icon download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825)

Comment: That makes sense, looking again, they are both minified files, however the first minified file (arrow icon) has a parent source file included in the solution, the second file does not - so even though minified it is seen as a stand alone CSS file.  Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You get these files as a result of bundling and minification process in Visual Studio. In other words, bundling lead to fewer HTTP requests, resulting in faster response times.

Check out web essentials, which can be used as VS add-on to facilitate bundling:
http://vswebessentials.com/features/bundling